# Error! Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead

Tags: python, django, django-models

Me está apareciendo este error en mi app de Djando y no lo comprendo porque no estoy asignando grupos a ningún usuario, espero puedan ayudarme.

No quisiera asignar grupos, solo clonar un usuario

El error es el siguiente:

> Error!
>
> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead. - {'password': '', 'last_login': None, 'is_superuser': False, 'username': 'gfn', 'first_name': 'gfn', 'last_name': 'nfg', 'email': 'sss@jjjj.com', 'is_staff': False, 'is_active': False, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 10, 20, 7, 29, 811484, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'groups': [], 'user_permissions': []}

Mi código:

```
 *views.py

class CloneUserView(CloneBaseView):
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_active') 
    template_name = "crud/form.html"
    form_class = CloneUserForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_user = form.clone_user()  

        self.success_url = reverse("users:user_list")  
        return super().form_valid(form)

     base.py (es donde estoy colocando código reutilizable)

    class CloneBaseView(FormView):
model = None  
form_class = None  
template_name = "crud/form.html"
success_url = ''

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class()
    return render(
        request,
        self.template_name,
        {"form": form}
    )

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
    error_render = render(
        request,
        self.template_name,
        {"form": form}
    )

    try:
        record = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        # Usa raise Http404 o redirige a una página de error según tu preferencia
        raise Http404(f'El registro con PK {self.kwargs.get("pk")} no existe.')

    if form.is_valid() and record:
        record_to_clone = model_to_dict(record)
        del record_to_clone["id"]
        new_data = record_to_clone | form.cleaned_data

        try:
            self.model.objects.create(**new_data)
            Message.success(request, f'El registro {record} ha sido clonado.')
            if self.success_url:
                return redirect(self.success_url)
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())
        except Exception as e:
            Message.error(request, f'{e} - {new_data}')
            return error_render

    Message.error(request, f'El registro {record} no se pudo clonar.')
    return error_render    

   *forms.py 

class CloneUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    is_active = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = "Nuevo Nombre de Usuario"

    def clone_user(self):
        # Crea un nuevo usuario con los datos del formulario
        user_data = {
            'username': self.cleaned_data['username'],
            'first_name': self.cleaned_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.cleaned_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'email': self.cleaned_data.get('email', ''),
            'is_active': self.cleaned_data.get('is_active', True),
        }
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        return new_user
```